# Jittery animation using animationFrame

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I whipped up a simple little spinner widget based on the Windows 8 loading animation, and I haven't been able to figure out why each dot appears to jitter slightly.  I've tried various things to normalize the values and haven't found anything that has smoothed it out.

http://jsbin.com/ilafov/16

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well I'd probably recommend using canvas for this to start.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hunch and screen shotted to be sure. Your animation doesn't appear to do any subpixel animation.

For animation to be truly smooth, to move a pixel by a pixel, you don't just hop from one to another, you imagine it moving by averages. The pixel slowly moves out of one space and into the next. You can simulate this by the pixel gradually fading out as the other fades in.

When I screen shotted your animation, I see all dots with no sign of sub pixel animation.

If you look at my business page: http://matthewrconsultancy.co.uk/start you'll see the cogs moving if you use something like Chrome. It uses SVG and SMIL animation, but you will see if you look at it magnified that animation is occurring on a sub pixel level. I'm afraid I don't have the time to figure out how to fix it for you just yet, but I can directly answer your main question of what is going wrong.

Comment: The best I can tell is that subpixel rendering simply isn't supported for elements.  The animation was not rounding to the nearest pixel.  I also tried using `zoom` to force it, but it's still jittery.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1) Try using canvas to animate the circles.  During initialization, you could draw one circle to an off-screen canvas and save its imageData (using getImageData) to an easily accessed variable.  During each frame of the animation, use putImageData for as many circles as you have in their respective coordinates on your main animating canvas.  Just remember to clear it every new frame.

2) Save your circle as a resolution independent image (SVG, CSS styling or Canvas with an API that updates its context based on the user's screen DPI and the browser's own displaying of pixels).  You could then try to move the circle using transform: translate3d(x, y, z).  This may provide smoother results, though I have heard that the hardware acceleration that this transform enables does prevent the browser from using sub-pixel ant-aliasing on certain elements.  Also remember that the transform property uses vendor prefixing.

Hope this helps!